# Removing an object from IOrderedEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, collections, iorderedenumerable

I sorted a dictionary like this:

```
var sortedListOfNodes = _nodeDictionary.Values.OrderBy((n) => n.Time);
```

Then I selected an element as such:

```
var selectedNode = sortedListOfNodes.First(n => n.Time - CurrentTime > new TimeSpan(1,0,0));
```

Then I did some processing on that node and at the end wanted to remove the node from the list, without destroying the sorted order.

Would the below maintain the order?

```
sortedListOfNodes = (IOrderedEnumerable<Node>)sortedListOfNodes.Where(node => node != selectedNode);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a call to `ToList` after `OrderBy`. Now you have a list you can manipulate (assuming you don't insert items it will stay in order).

```
var sortedListOfNodes = _nodeDictionary.Values.OrderBy((n) => n.Time).ToList();
var selectedNode = sortedListOfNodes.First(n => n.Time - CurrentTime > new TimeSpan(1,0,0));
sortedListOfNodes.Remove(selectedNode);
```

On a side note your example of casting the result of `Where` to `IOrderedEnumerable<Node>` would fail at runtime with a casting failure. The `Where` you are calling is a concrete type that does not implement that interface.